# Mysql how to select count aggregation results at 10-minute intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb

I want to query the count of a certain column every 10 minutes up to the current time.

Assume that the actual data is as follows.

```
| access_no |     in_datetime     |
-----------------------------------
|   1       | 2021-09-16 09:10:30 |
|-----------|---------------------|
|   2       | 2021-09-16 09:15:05 |
|-----------|---------------------|
|   3       | 2021-09-16 10:03:23 |
|-----------|---------------------|
|   4       | 2021-09-16 11:13:53 |
|-----------|---------------------|
|   5       | 2021-09-16 11:30:10 |
|-----------|---------------------|
```

At this time, the desired output result is as follows.

```
| hh:mm     | au  |
-------------------
|   09:10   |  2  |
|-----------|-----|
|   09:20   |  0  |
|-----------|-----|
|   09:30   |  0  |
|-----------|-----|
|   09:40   |  0  |
|-----------|-----|
|   09:50   |  0  |
|-----------|-----|
|   10:00   |  1  |
|-----------|-----|
|   10:10   |  1  |
|-----------|-----|
|   10:20   |  0  |
|-----------|-----|
|   10:30   |  1  |
|-----------|-----|
```

And the query I've made so far is as follows.

```
SELECT
   case 
        when substr(in_datetime,15,2) < '10' then concat(substr(in_datetime,12,2),':00')
        when substr(in_datetime,15,2) >='10' and substr(in_datetime,15,2)<'20' then concat(substr(in_datetime,12,2),':10')
      when substr(in_datetime,15,2) >='20' and substr(in_datetime,15,2)<'30' then concat(substr(in_datetime,12,2),':20')
      when substr(in_datetime,15,2) >='30' and substr(in_datetime,15,2)<'40' then concat(substr(in_datetime,12,2),':30')
      when substr(in_datetime,15,2) >='40' and substr(in_datetime,15,2)<'50' then concat(substr(in_datetime,12,2),':40')
      when substr(in_datetime,15,2) >='50' and substr(in_datetime,15,2)<'60' then concat(substr(in_datetime,12,2),':50')
   END as hhmm,
   count(access_no) as au
FROM tbl_access

where date(out_datetime) = str_to_date('20210916', '%Y%m%d')
and in_datetime is not null

group by substr(in_datetime,1,10) ,
   case 
        when substr(in_datetime,15,2)<'10' then concat(substr(in_datetime,12,2),':00')
        when substr(in_datetime,15,2) >='10' and substr(in_datetime,15,2)<'20' then concat(substr(in_datetime,12,2),':10')
      when substr(in_datetime,15,2) >='20' and substr(in_datetime,15,2)<'30' then concat(substr(in_datetime,12,2),':20')
      when substr(in_datetime,15,2) >='30' and substr(in_datetime,15,2)<'40' then concat(substr(in_datetime,12,2),':30')
      when substr(in_datetime,15,2) >='40' and substr(in_datetime,15,2)<'50' then concat(substr(in_datetime,12,2),':40')
      when substr(in_datetime,15,2) >='50' and substr(in_datetime,15,2)<'60' then concat(substr(in_datetime,12,2),':50')
   END
```

However, in the result of this query, the value of the time when there is no data is not retrieved as shown below.

```
| hh:mm     | au  |
-------------------
|   09:10   |  2  |
|-----------|-----|
|   10:00   |  1  |
|-----------|-----|
|   10:10   |  1  |
|-----------|-----|
|   10:30   |  1  |
|-----------|-----|
```

How can I retrieve the time when there is no data up to the current time?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then this can be solved with a calendar table.

You can create a list of times using a [recursive cte](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) and then format them using [DATE_FORMAT()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date_format/) to display only `hh:mm` as per your existing query.

```
with recursive times as (
    select '1970-01-01 00:00' t 
    union all
    select t + interval 10 minute 
    from times 
    where t  <= '1970-01-01 23:40'
 )
 select 
     DATE_FORMAT(t, '%H:%i') 'hh:mm'
 from 
     times
```

Output:

| hh:mm |
| --- |
| 00:00 |
| 00:10 |
| 00:20 |
| ... |

You can then join this to your existing query to return a row for every time.